# Function call not taking effect Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have an issue with Ocaml where I am trying to remove a particular value from a set and the print out the set excluding the removed value. Each time I write the function, I get an error. This is the function.

```
let ac_ch = ac_change p set in 
let remove = SS.remove pretty_print ac_ch in
remove;;
let _= (SS.iter print_endline ac_ch) in
let _= print_newline () in
let _= print_newline () in
let _= print_newline () in
```

But each time I run this I get the error: `Error: Unbound value ac_ch`. I think it has to do with terminating the function call `remove` with `;;` however, is there another way to call this function and let it have its effect? I'm really confused here

Comment: `ac_ch` *is* unbound after the `;;`

Comment: What function are you talking about? And why does your code end in a stray `in`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that SS repesents a string set module declared something like this:

```
module SS = Set.Make(String)
```

Your first expression looks like this:

```
let ac_ch = ... in let remove = ... in remove
```

The definitions of `ac_ch` and `remove` are local to this expression. So there's no binding for either of these names in the later code.

You say you want the first expression to "have its effect", but sets in OCaml are immutable. I.e., there are no effects that you can apply to them. The expression produces a value `remove`, a set with an element removed, but the value isn't used anywhere later in the computation. There is no effect on any previously existing set.

You need to recast your computation taking into account the immutability of sets.

Something like this might be closer:

```
let ac_ch = ac_change p set in
let remove = SS.remove pretty_print ac_ch in
let _= (SS.iter print_endline remove) in
let _= print_newline () in
let _= print_newline () in
let _= print_newline ()
```